# Iteratively adding new columns to a list of data frames

Tags: r, list, for-loop, dataframe

I am trying to write some code that iterates through a list of data frames, adding to each a new column that contains the same values as an older column but shifted by 1. The first value in this column will be NA. Below is my code:

```
for(dataframe in 1:length(listOfDataFrames)){
    newColumn <- c(NA)
    for(row in 1:(nrow(listOfDataFrames[[dataframe]]) - 1)){
        newColumn <- append(newColumn, listOfDataFrames[[dataframe]]$oldColumn[row])
    }
    mutate(listOfDataFrames[[i]], newColumn = newColumn)
}
```

However, when I execute this code in R, I get an error on the first dataframe:

```
replacement has 894 rows, data has 895
```

What could be causing this error? Sorry if this is an easy question, I am not an expert in R.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You code is a concentration of things you **should avoid** in R:

1. Don't use `for` when you can use `lapply` or more genrally xxapply family.
2. Don't append row of a data.frame inside loop. This very inefficient. You should pre-allocate. Using `lapply` will do it for you.
3. Don't use `$` inside function. You should use `[` operator
4. No need to loop over a data.frame when you can do it in a vectorized manner.

Here How I would do this :

```
lapply(listOfDataFrames, function(DX){

        ## I assume that your DX has and "oldColum" variable
        transform(DX,newColumn =c(NA,head(oldColumn,-1))

})
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. I'm not used to the lapply function so I went to for-loops by instinct, but your code is better! I hadn't considered using the head function to create the new column.

Regarding $, why is it considered bad? I've seen it used inside functions in tutorials such as this:
https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~spector/R.pdf

Comment: I don't for the tutorial , but the use of `$` is more permissive due to the partial matching ( type this for example:  `ll <- list(yyaa=1); ll$y` ) , so it is a source of error/bugs. Better to use it only for R console.