# Building a Dataframe Column-by-Column in R

Tags: r

Is there a way for me to iteratively build a dataframe in `R`? I would be interested in knowing how I would do so either by adding column-by-column or row-by-row. I have been trying for some time now and find myself stuck.

Here is some code that I have tried:

```
    line <- as.list(strsplit(line, ", "))[[1]]  # make into list
    col_names = names(idx_for_cell_counts_by_gene_id)
    df <- data.frame()  # here is where I get stuck - want an empty dataframe
    
    for (x in 1:length(col_names)) {
      column_name <- col_names[[x]]
      information <- line[[x]]
      
      df$column_name <- information
    }
```

I have tried looking at some SO examples ([#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814912/error-replacement-has-x-rows-data-has-y), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30948924/iteratively-adding-new-columns-to-a-list-of-data-frames)) but to no avail. Is there something I should do to instantiate an empty dataframe (or, better yet, a dataframe with only 'column headers' and now rows) in `R`?

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and in particular provide a complete self contained code.  We can't run your code since the inputs are missing.

Comment: You could create an empty `data.frame` with `as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 0))`.  Alternatively, you could create a "headers-only" `data.frame` with `as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = length(col_names), dimnames = list(c(), col_names)))`.

Answer (score 2):

One issue is that `df$column_name` creates a column named column_name. It doesn't use the value in the object named column_name. Making a representative example and walking through it will show you:

```
df <- data.frame(placeholder = 0)

column_name <- "my_col"

# The following will create a column named "column_name"
df$column_name <- 0
# df
#   placeholder column_name
# 1           0           0

# The following will create a column with the value inside of the object `column_name`
df[,column_name] <- 0
# df
#   placeholder column_name my_col
# 1           0           0      0
```

Another issue you have is that you're making a data.frame of length 0. That means that any column you add needs to be a matching length. All columns in a dataframe must be the same length.

One way to deal with this is to create a placeholder column when you create the dataframe and then remove it later. `df <- data.frame(placeholder = boolean(length(line[[1]])))`. There may be other more elegant ways to handle this.

Comment: Perfect! Also, for the 'placeholder', I used the following ```R    # empty dataframe
    holder <- line!='hey'
    gene_info <- data.frame(placeholder = holder[[1]])```

Comment: It just occurred to me that it might be easier to create a dataframe with column names but no rows and then use `add_row()` to add data to the columns.